# "Encountered" error which should not be there

Tags: java, eclipse, token, abstract-syntax-tree, javacc

I am currently working on a simple language with a parser using JavaCC, Eclipse and the JTB. I am doing this for learning purposes. When I run the .java file it gives me the following Error:

```
Encountered " "var" "var "" at line 2, column 5.
Was expecting: ":" ...
```

But when I look through my code there is no such thing at line 2??!!
I know that this error should not be there I have been debugging due to a previous error for like 2 hours now...

*EDIT*
this is my token code that includes the "var":

```
TOKEN : 
{
  < REQUIRE: "require" >
| < IF: "if" >
| < WHILE:"while" >
| < VAR:"var" >
| < STOP:"stop" >
| < EXEC:"exec" >
| < ELSE:"else" >
}
```

and this is the rule definition for "var":

```
void VariableDeclaration():{}
{

  "var" VariableName() "=" MathExpression() "."
}

void VariableAssign():{}
{
  VariableName() "=" MathExpression() "."
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you include the code that it is trying to read?  At least the first bit?

Comment: @Pokechu22 the first lines? sure

Comment: There error pops up because the parser encountered token "var" when it was expecting one of a set of tokens that does not include "var".  If you want a better answer you'll have to post both the input text and the relevant part of the grammar. If you turn on parser debugging you will see exactly what is going on for yourself.

Comment: When it parsed `"var "` it looks like you got whitespace at the end. That might be why it's giving you the error. Your grammar might be correct but since it's seeing `"var "` instead of just `"var"` it would give you an error. Look over your code and see if you're properly ignoring whitespace when you're supposed to.

Comment: @mcon all the whitespaces are ok nothing wrong here :(

Comment: What's the input?  And do you have tokenizer productions to skip white space? (E.g. `SKIP: {" "}`.)

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell I have skip tokenizers and theres no input im just compiling the grammar file

Comment: @ANON Your question says "When I run the .java file it gives me the following Error:". Now you are contradicting that.  What program is giving you the error message?  JavaCC, JTB, or JJTRee?  Link to the actual file and maybe someone can help.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell yeah that last comment was just a brainfart. I am running the .java file.

Comment: @ANON Can you post the input? It might help a bit more.

Comment: @mcon no input just running as app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message was output because the parser encountered the character sequence "var", which was recognized as a token kind that the parser was not in a state to expect at the time it was encountered. One of the acceptable token kinds is associated with the character sequence ":".

In short the sequence of tokens was not one that was in the language described by the grammar.

If you want to know more than that, you should ask a new question.  E.g. Given this grammar ..., why is this input ..., causing my JavaCC generatted parser to issue this error message ... . But, before you go copying large grammars into stack exchange, you should (a) try to solve the problem yourself --for example using JavaCC's excellent debugging options-- and (b) boil the problem down to a minimal failing example.

Comment: actually all the function/keywords are described in the grammar as one token kind but it only gives me an error on "var" which is used to define